# Regex for password validation using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for password validation using JavaScript which should contain at least one numeric and one special character symbol in (* ^ % $ # @ ) and more than one alpha characters. Currently I am using below code snippet, which is not working:

```
/^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]{2}))(?=.*\d)(?=.*(\*))(?=.*(^))(?=.*(%))(?=.*(#))(?=.*($))(?=.*(@))$/
```

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: https://stormpath.com/blog/5-myths-password-security#1-myth-complexity-trumps-length

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand why you're using positive lookahead constructs for password validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line up all your requirements as assertions, then match the string
if the assertions are satisfied.
`(?i)^(?=(?:.*[a-z]){2})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[*^%$#@]).+$`

```
 (?i)                          # In line modifier - case insensitive
 ^                             # BOS
 (?=                           # Assert - at least 2 alpha's
      (?: .* [a-z] ){2}
 )
 (?= .* \d )                   # Assert - at least 1 numeric
 (?= .* [*^%$#@] )             # Assert - at least 1 special

 .+                            # Match all here
 $                             # EOS
```

Comment: Thanks @sln ! It worked. Thanks all for your comments. :)

Comment: @HarshitGupta - You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.